# Audio interfaces just broken on my iMac?

Tags: macos

For the past year I've owned two audio interfaces. Semi-recently I obtained a wonderful new iMac and I love it. I own a M-Audio Fast Track and a Focusrite 2i2 and although I love this new iMac I'm having extreme issues with these audio interfaces. When I talk or record anything the audio stutters and sometimes just cuts out completely. It's the same case for both devices. I've had this problem since before I upgraded to OSX Mavericks and I don't know if it related to my installation of Adobe Premiere Pro. I can't use my audio interfaces at all with Premiere so I just use it as an audio device for other editing software. Anyone else have the same problem or anybody have some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting my Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 to appear as an option in Adobe Premiere Pro CC on a Mac running Mavericks. It showed up in Audition, just not in Premiere.

Go to Audio Midi Setup in the Utilities folder on your Mac (or just search for Audio Midi Setup in Spotlight) and look for Adobe Premiere Pro in the list. There should be a check box to add the audio interface there. Then be sure to quit Audio Midi Setup. I think it doesn't stick unless you quit.

Then go into Premiere Preferences > Audio Hardware and choose System Default Input/Output. This should make it work. It did for me!

Answer (score 0):

If your iMac has a fusion drive (FD) in it I recommend breaking up the FD and working from the SSD and HDD separately. This is the only thing that fixed the issues I had with Audio and my iMac.

Here are some thread on Apple Support discussing these issues:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5617629?start=0&tstart=0
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5659615?start=0&tstart=0